# Continue boot with offline fstab disk (linux/systemd)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, systemd, fstab

During boot, with pre-systemd versions of Ubuntu server (eg. 14.04), if a non-critical fstab disk was offline, the system would wait to mount the disk (30s iirc), timeout and continue booting.

Since upgrading through 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, thanks to systemd's dependencies I presume, a missing fstab disk stops the boot process resulting in the "Emergency mode... Press Enter for Maintenance" prompt at boot time.

1. Is there a way to change this behaviour by default? Ie. simply continue booting or an option to flag disks as non-critical?
2. Failing that, is there a straightforward systemctl command to 'continue booting ignoring missing disk' from maintenance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `/etc/fstab` entries for your mounts you can add systemd specific options, including the [`nofail`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#nofail) option will instruct systemd that the boot can continue without waiting for the mount unit and regardless whether the mount point can be mounted successfully.

You can add the options [`x-systemd.device-timeout`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.device-timeout=) and or [`x-systemd.mount-timeout`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.mount-timeout=) to customize time-outs.

Comment: Thanks. In the absence of `nofail` do the `x-systemd.*timeout` options allow boot to continue without stopping for input on "Emergency mode... Press Enter for Maintenance"? If possible I'd like to wait for a timeout period and continue booting if unsuccessful.